# Check if property exists DataTable.ExtendedProperties Property

Tags: c#, datatable

I added an ExtendedProperty to one of my Datatable like the way explained in this link  [DataTable.ExtendedProperties Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.extendedproperties(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        dt.ExtendedProperties.Add("PageBreak",false);
```

i was wondering if there is a native method to check if this property exists other than `if != null` , like the javaScript `hasOwnProperty()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to do this:

```
dt.ExtendedProperties.ContainsKey("PageBreak")
```

`ExtendedProperties` is of type `PropertyCollection` which inherits from `Hashtable`. So you can use [`Hashtable.ContainsKey` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the key is already exists...